# Android Jetpack DataStore

Tags: android, datastore, android-jetpack-datastore

I want use Jetpack DataStore in my app and according to setup instruction in: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore I have added the following to my build.gradle.kts(:app)

```
dependencies {
        implementation("androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0")
}
```

then to store key-value pairs I have added this line at the top level of my kotlin file:
`val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = "settings")`

but on this step after `import android.content.Context` to my kotlin file, I have **Unresolved reference: dataStore** error and **Property "dataStore" is never used** warning

Comment: Could you put the actual code the error appears on?

Comment: @RyanM it's actual code

Answer (score 0):

You should have the following two dependencies in your app:`build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore:$data_store_version"
implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:$data_store_version"
```

Then at least following imports in your Kotlin file:

```kotlin
import android.content.Context
import androidx.datastore.core.DataStore
import androidx.datastore.preferences.preferencesDataStore

private val Context.dataStore: DataStore<androidx.datastore.preferences.core.Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(
        name = "PREFERENCES_NAME"
    )
```

Comment: doesn't work for me